# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php, php-curl

After changing web server, i get "

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...".

I guess this is because I'm now using another version of PHP. Can't really figure out what the problem is. Can anyone help? The line that gets the error message is "`if (count (json_decode ($result, true)['r']) != 0) {`".

```
function g ($t) {
    $output = '';

    // Checking that there is a cpe hostname
    if (!empty ($t)) {
        // Getting the id of the device
        $curl = curl_init ();

        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '...=' . $t);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close ($curl);

        if (count (json_decode ($result, true)['r']) != 0) {
            // Getting the configuration for the device
            $curl = curl_init ();

            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '...=' . json_decode ($result, true)['r'][0]['id']);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close ($curl);

            // If the configuration of the device was found
            if (count (json_decode ($result, true)['c']['r']['c']) != 0) {
                $output = json_decode ($result, true)['c']['r']['c'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

I tried looking for other posts here on Stackoverflow with simulare problems without any luck.

Comment: What version of PHP exactly? There are no syntax errors in this code, on any supported version: https://3v4l.org/fLScq

Comment: It worked on PHP 5.6.40, but not on PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: The solution to that really is to upgrade to a supported version and stop using one which went out of support 8 years ago!! You are leaving yourself vulnerable to all sorts of potential security problems, not to mention missing out on new features - including syntax enhancements (!), performance improvements etc.

Comment: Anyway the issue in 5.3 seems to be using array syntax at the end of a function call. So instead you should just separate the function calls out, and use some variables. To be honest it makes the code a lot more readable anyway, and also reduces the number of times you are repeatedly decoding the JSON (which is inefficient). Try this version: https://3v4l.org/EA7O4#v5.3.29